# Merge [advanced-format] and [4k-sectors]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[Advanced Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format), at least in its current state, specifies sectors of 4096 bytes in size, but questions involving 4K AF drives have been tagged as both [advanced-format](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/advanced-format) and [4k-sectors](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/4k-sectors).  Can someone merge these tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would agree on merging [4k-sectors](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/4k-sectors) into [advanced-format](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/advanced-format) and also synonymizing them.

---

```
updating post history, 20 rows affected
updating posts, 14 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 13 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [advanced-format] and [4k-sectors] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym 4k-sectors -> advanced-format was approved!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```

Comment: As a ♦moderator, can you merge them?

Comment: @DragonLord: Yes, and I just did. I just wanted to give others the chance to possibly object :)